# Blockchain.info testnet payment APIs

Tags: blockchain.info, payment-processors

I have created a testnet wallet on [testnet.blockchain.info](https://testnet.blockchain.info) and added some testnet bitcoins to it.

I want to test the payment APIs so I am following [the documentation](https://testnet.blockchain.info/api/api_receive) on how to Generate a receive address. Yet I do not see a way or an URI to register a testnet receive address.

I tried to use it as is and I've put my testnet xpub in the query but I get this error:

```
{
    "message": "Invalid xpub format",
    "description": "Ensure you provide an xpub key, rather than an address"
}
```

Anyone had success using blockchain's payment APIs with testnet before?

Answer (score 0):

Blockchain.info doesn't support API for Testnet network.

That API Pages for Mainnet network. What you can use [blockcypher](https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/bitcoin/?php#blockcypher-supported-language-sdks) as an alternative, they're supporting Testnet for bitcoin.